# Beautiful Soup isn't giving me the expected results for title extraction from a webpage in Python, what can I do?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been trying to extract all the titles off this webpage, :-`https://www.ycombinator.com/companies?industry=B2B%20Software%20and%20Services&status=Active&status=Public&status=Inactive&tags=Fintech&tags=Developer%20Tools&tags=Artificial%20Intelligence&tags=Analytics`. e.g. (gitlab, deel,fivetran, etc). I am using the beautifulSoup package for this task, but it doesn't give me the correct results.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ycombinator.com/companies?industry=B2B%20Software%20and%20Services&status=Active&status=Public&status=Inactive&tags=Fintech&tags=Developer%20Tools&tags=Artificial%20Intelligence&tags=Analytics'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
for a_tag in a_tags:
    div_tag = a_tag.find('div', class_='right')
    if div_tag:
        span_tags = div_tag.find_all('span')
        for span_tag in span_tags:
            text = span_tag.get_text(strip=True)
            print(text)
```

I used this to do the task. I first found out all the  tags on the page, and then went inside to the  tags, and then finally to the , where I suppose the titles I want are present. But,it still doesn't show any result. Anybody know a fix to this?

Comment: For this particular one, use Selenium, it will be easier than figuring out a complex header & POST payload.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get any results because the titles (GitLab, Deel, Fivetran, etc) you're looking for is part of search results that involves javascript and it takes a few seconds to get loaded on the page. There is no way you can do it with simple `requests` as it does not support javascript. But you can achieve the same using `Selenium`.

[image]

Here is how you can approach the problem using Selenium:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome()
url = "https://www.ycombinator.com/companies?industry=B2B%20Software%20and%20Services&status=Active&status=Public&status=Inactive&tags=Fintech&tags=Developer%20Tools&tags=Artificial%20Intelligence&tags=Analytics"
driver.get(url)

results = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.WxyYeI15LZ5U_DOM0z8F')))

print(f"total search results: {len(results)}")
for result in results:
    print(result.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.right>div>span').text)
```

output:

```
total search results: 40
GitLab
Deel
Fivetran
Checkr
Retool
Podium
Algolia
Modern Treasury
Sift
Pave
Mux
Jasper.ai
Apollo
Mashgin
Veriff
Airbyte
Teleport
People.ai
Sendbird
Mixpanel
Human Interest
Heap
Frubana Inc
Replit
QuickNode
Middesk
Supabase
TRM Labs
InfluxData
Bitrise
Hightouch
Instabug
Mezmo
Routable
HackerRank
Duffel
Deepgram
RevenueCat
TrueNorth
Nuvocargo
```